# Netilat yadayim without a keli?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, netilat-yadayim-washing

It is known that the *Sefer Halakhoth Gedholoth* codifies that since only the descendants of Aharon HaKohen were strictly commanded regarding *netilath yadhayim* with a *keli*, it is therefore enough for a *yisrael* to simply immerse their hands/fingers in a vessel containing water without the need to pour it over the hands.

I have also read that in a *sha^ath ha-dohaq* one may use a faucet to wash before prayer.

Are there any other sources from Geonim or Rishonim that permit washing for prayer without the use of a *keli*? Are there sources that discuss the difference in obligations for washing as they apply to a *kohen* or a *yisrael*?

Comment: "_It is known that_ ..." by whom? Where?

Comment: Ithere seems like you are asking about teffilah,but you also bring reasons for washing for bread? The first washing in the morning has three reasons,the Rosh,Rashba, and the Zohar (Rauch raah) for bread we do it because of serach tumah,so which are you asking?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79306/759

Comment: See [this post](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79313/9215) may be that the answer to your question is entirely included in it.

Answer (score 2):

Washing for bread, or for Tefilla? Bread is more stringent, but tefilla would seem to be fine from a tap.

**Sources (Based on Beis Yosef OC 4:22)**

**Rosh (Brachos 9:23)** writes that *netilas yadayim* of *shacharis* (which he himself rules is for the purpose of *tefilla*) does not need a *kli*.

**Mordechai (Brachos 192)** and **Ran (Chulin 37b [dapei HaRif])** also write that a *kli* is not necessary in the morning.

[I presume that this would apply to all other *tefillos*, as at least part of the morning washing is to prepare for *shacharis*, even according to the Rashba.]

**Rashba (Teshuvos 1:191)** writes that only *netilas yadayim* of *shacharis* needs a *kli*, as it is "like a Kohen washing". Other *tefillos* do not need.

The only source I have found who **would** require a *kli* for *tefilla* is the Gra* (Bi'ur HaGra OC 4:7) who comments that *lechatchila* a *kli* should be used for ***tefilla***, not just in the morning. However, the simple reading of the Shulchan Aruch there, and the Beis Yosef himself, imply that only the morning has such a *halacha*, in order to fulfill *lechatchila* the opinion of the Rashba mentioned above.

*I know, not a Rishon...

Comment: the question sought "sources from Geonim or Rishonim"

Comment: @DoubleAA, SA isn't a Rishon?

Comment: That's debatable. Plus MB definitely isn't

Comment: @DoubleAA, true... I was just quoting him for clarification. Suppose you're right though.

Answer (score 1):

For netila before prayer of Mincha or Arvit,  nobody seems to  require a keli.

For netila see SA  **OC 4, 18**. see Kaf Hachayim. Several cases needs threefold netila but the Kaf Hachayim sk 61 in name of Eliahou Rabba  says that there is no need of keli (but I understand that we need Koach gavra). See Shaare Teshuva sk 12 who mentioned also threefold but not  Keli.

In conclusion keli for netilat Yadaym of meal only is obligatory; for netilat  yadaym of shacharit it's needed lechatechilla, and for the last prayers ,  even lechatechilla no keli is needed.  Several cases need threefold netila and coach gavra but not keli. Keli for  morning prayer is addressed in **Shut Harashba**  (for details see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79313/9215) post which cites also  **Rabenu Yerucham**  and the **Rosh** against the opinion of the Rashba),  needing 3 fold for the last cases is addressed in Acharonim.

#### All the Rishonim cited in Bet Yosef (OC 4)  didn't require keli for Mincha and Arvit. All this Rishonim except the Rashba didn't require a keli for tefilat shacharit.