# Which authorities do not require a vessel (keli) for washing before praying?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, netilat-yadayim-washing

[Rav Aryeh Lebovitz in his shiur at around 6'58''](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/744040/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Ten_Minute_Halacha_-_Washing_for_Davening) quotes authorities that do not require washing with a vessel (keli) for washing before praying. 
(I do not have the sefer he quotes. )

Who are these authorities?

Closely related [Washing before Davening - 1 or 3 times?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35272/washing-before-davening-1-or-3-times)

Answer (score 4):

See Shulchan Aruch OC 4, 7:

> **טוב להקפיד** בנטילת ידיים שחרית בכל הדברים המעכבים בנטילת ידיים לסעודה.
>   הגה: מיהו **אינו מעכב,** לא כלי ( *מגן אברהם:* פירוש, בדיעבד היכא דאי אפשר בעניין אחר; אבל היכא דאפשר, טוב להקפיד) ולא כוח גברא ושאר הדברים הפוסלים בנטילת הסעודה (מרדכי ריש פרק אלו דברים, תשובת רשב"א סימן קצ"ה).‏

Bet Yosef:

> וכתב ***רבינו ירוחם***  בנתיב י"ו חלק ו': ומברך "על נטילת ידים", על שם הכלי שנקרא אנטל. ואף **שלא נתקן הכלי אלא   בשביל נטילת האכילה,** מכל מקום לא ישנה הברכה. וכן     כתב   ***הרא"ש***  ‏

A vessel was instituted by Chachamim for washing of meal only. But Lechatechilla, the SA (based on a deduction from the words of the Gemara by the Shut Harashba (¹), and according to the Zohar) says that  its good to make a point to take   a vessel. But it is not meykar Hadin. The nusach of the blessing itself makes allusion to the vesssel which is called natla. Bet Yosef makes the same deduction from the Gemara Berachot 15a

> he should heed the call of nature and wash his hands  ("ויטול ידיו")  and put on tefillin and recite the Shema' and say the tefillah:

**In Shulchan Aruch and commentators  on the page(¹),  nobody needs vessel  bediavad and everybody advised to use vessel  lechatechilla.**

See SA OC 232, 2:

> אם יש לו מים וצריך ליטול ידיו כדי להתפלל אף על פי שאינו יודע להם שום לכלוך ולא יברך (יזועיין לעיל סימן צ"ב סעיף ה').
>   הגה: ואפילו עומד מלמודו יטול ידיו יטלתפלה (מנהגים).
>   ואם אין לו מים מזומנים כאינו צריך ליטול:
>   ‏

It is true for Mincha and Arvit too.

---

<sup>(¹): Thanks to @Avrohom Yitzchock I added this note:</sup>

Someone asked the Rashba (the Shut is quoted in Bet Yosef  here) about the fact that the blessing for washing of the morning mentioned a vessel (natla)  when the halacha doesn't require this.

Rashba answered with  **four  arguments:**

1. The *custom everywhere*  is to wash with a vessel fulfilling the same conditions required for washing before a meal.
2. Gemara in Chulin says that washing of morning can be useful for the subsequent meal, and for meal we need a vessel,  so the morning washing is also made with a vessel.
3. Gemara uses different expressions for the washing before morning prayer and the washing before Shabbat. The verb  "notel" used for the morning washing refers to the vessel used.
4. The specificity of the washing of  morning prayer is linked to the fact that  Chachamim made a special blessing for this washing.  A washing with a blessing of  asher kiddeshanu is a mitsva derabanan statuted  "כעין דאורייתא "  (similar to washing which are mitsvot of Tora)  i. e.  similar to kiddush Yadaym of  Kohanim,  which requires a vessel.

So,  for Rashba maybe that the blessing of netilat yadaym requires not only  lechatechilla,  but  perhaps even bediavad,  a vessel.

Anyway,  the OP was asking for an opinion that allows without vessel at all even lechatechilla. For now I have not found such opinion in Acharonim (regarding netilat yadaym of mornings prayer). *But Rabenu Yerucham,  the Rosh,  the Hagahot Mordechai and the Ran didn't need keli,  even lechatechilla even for Shacharit.*

**Note:** All this issue regards the washing before morning prayer but for Mincha and Arvit I didn't find someone who needs a keli lechatechilla. The unique reason to require a vessel for morning prayer netilat is the text of blessing according to the Rashba.  Last opinions are more lenient than Rashba regarding the lechatechilla of the netila before Shacharit, a forciori regarding Mincha and Arvit.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. But I had the impression from Rav Lebovitz that there were authorities that do not require washing with a vessel lechatchillo and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I am searching. I remember something in name of the Rashba but I up to now.

Comment: Yes - this is it, I think: בשו"ת הרשב"א (חלק א' סימן קצא) כתב, מאי שנא תפילת השחר מתפילת מנחה וערבית שרק בשחרית נוטלים בכלי, והשיב, שיש לומר דכיון שבשחר אנו נעשים כבריה חדשה דכתיב (איכה ג') "חדשים לבקרים רבה אמונתך" וכו', ועל דבר זה תקנו בשחר כל אותן ברכות שאנו מברכין בכל בוקר ובוקר. ולפיכך אנו צריכין להתקדש בקדושתו וליטול ידינו מן הכלי ככהן שמקדש ידיו מן הכיור קודם עבודתו. which I found [here](http://www.shtaygen.co.il/?CategoryID=1625&ArticleID=6479).

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchock see edit please

Comment: Your edit does not include the important part that I quoted in my comment above - that is that only for shacharis do you need a keli!

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchock yes,  the first part of your quote is included in number  3, the next in number  4. I tried to make this as understandable as possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52312/discussion-between-kouty-and-avrohom-yitzchok).

Comment: The Vilna Gaon paskins that one must wash before each of the 3 tefilos during the day and to wash with a cup as one washes for bread and to make an al nitilas yadoiyim. Bay'ur HaGra, siman 4 sif katan 9

Comment: @joelschnur shkoyech I'll read it later.

Comment: @joelschnur I don't understand what is the Gra, it seems a quote of a stuff in the shut Harashba. It is not clear because the Gra wrote כנ"ל without citing the Rashba. Tsarich Yun.

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchock I edited the answer to make clear that for  Mincha,  if I understand right,  needs keli

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I mean nobody needs keli

Answer (score 1):

I found three sources:

[Shulchan Oruch Harav O Ch 4 (1)](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/1/4)

> למעשה לחזר אחר מים גם לתפלת מנחה וערבית עד מיל אבל לא לברך שספק ברכות
>   להקל **אך אין צריך ליטול מן הכלי**  אלא יכול לשכשך בתוכו ואפילו אינו שלם
>   ואפילו במים שבקרקע ואפילו אין בהם רביעית ואפילו מים הפסולים לנטילת
>   ידים לסעודה  כי מאחר שנטילת ידים לתפלה אינה אלא משום נקיון אין צריך
>   כלי  ולא כח נותן  ולא מים כשרים ולא שאר דברים המעכבים בנטילת ידים
>   לסעודה

[Ketzos HaShulchan 12 (3)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7720&hilite=16fa4a9a-33e4-4c8e-8fae-8da7c4b6e12d&st=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D&pgnum=72)

> אם הסיח דעתו מידיו אחר נט״י שחרית צריך לחזור וליטול ידיו  לק"ש ולתפלה
>   אעפ"י שאינו יודע להם שום לכלוך  (אבל  לת״ת ולשאר ברכות סתם ידים כשרות
>   ואין היסח הדעת פוסל בהם)  וצריך ליטול עד הפרק דהיינו עד חבור האצבעות
>   לכף היד ויקה עוד  מים בכפו וישפשף כפית הידים זו בזו לנקותם לקיים ארחץ
>   בנקיון  כפי. **אך אינו צריך כלי ולא כח נותן  ולא מים כשרים ולא שאר דברים
>   המעכבים בנט״י לסעודה** ואינו צריך לברך על נטילה זו

[Teshuvas Rashba part 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1376&st=%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%A7+%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D+&pgnum=93&hilite=)

> מדקאמר נוטל ידיו ולא קאמר רוחץ ידיו כמו שאמרי בערב רוחץ פניו ידיו
>   ורגליו. **משמע לכאורה שצריך *בשחר* ליטול ידיו בכלי. ואם תשאל מאי שנא תפילה
>   השחר מתפילת מנחה וערבית**

.......